# Better to mention a paper as "under review" on the CV, or provide a paper's arXiv link (on the CV) to a selection committee?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, cv, job, preprint

I have a research article (a large work that lasted years) that just went "under review", in a well-regarded journal.

More or less at the same time, i.e. in around 1 week, there will be the deadline for a couple of positions that I like a lot, and that I would like to apply for.

In my opinion, that paper under review can make a difference in the selection process for the two open positions.

Now, I have the following doubt:

Should I just mention the paper under review on the CV (something like, "paper XXX is under review in YYY Journal"), or it can be better to post the manuscript on arXiv, or other preprint servers, in order to be read by the selection commettee (i.e. by adding the paper's arXiv link to the CV)?

---

Why this doubt?

Although the paper underwent an "internal-review" from the co-authors (3 authors in total), and it went through the "first assessment" from the editors of the journal (both an Associate Editor and the Editor-In-Chief), who eventually decided to send the paper out for a peer-review, I am still thinking that a "good" moment for sending the paper out, in a preprint server, would be after the first modifications of the paper, as a consequence of the first round of review. But to arrive to the first revision/modifications of the paper, it can obviously take several months.

On the internet, I found discordant opinions on such a matter, and also after internal discussions with my group, I am not sure which is the best option.

Comment: I think this might be field dependent. Which field are you in?

Comment: Half physics, half geography. :-)

Comment: Why not both? In my field, math, it is pretty much a norm to post on arXiv before (or simultaneously with) submitting to a journal.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Moishe Kohan :-)

Comment: "*something like, 'paper XXX is under review in YYY Journal'*" I recommend against mentioning the journal. The journal name becomes relevant for your CV once your paper has been accepted there. Before that, this feels like showing off with a prize that you haven't been awarded, yet.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck, thanks for your comment :-) However, I do not understand why to name a Journal can be seen as a showing off, instead of just as a simple information.. :-)

Comment: @Ommo: Journal names in a publication list/CV have two purposes: (i) They provide bibliographic infomation to make it easier to identify and find an article. (ii) The reputation of the jounral is, to some extent, used as a proxy for the quality of your research. Part (i) does only apply after your paper has appeared (at least online). Part (ii) is the "show off" part. Note that showing off is completely legimate in an application - so you should show off your accomplishments in your CV. The problem is that the journal name is not an accomplishment, yet, as long as the paper is under review.

Comment: @Ommo: I'm sorry, I don't understand your last comment. My sentence that you cite before "Therefore" does not imply what you claim after "Therefore". You're of course free to disagree with me and insist to mention the name of the journal in which your paper is under review. Please just be advised that some people (like me) won't receive this very positively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you post on arXiv (or anywhere) make certain that the journal you submitted to permits preprints. Many do, especially in some fields but some don't.

You can also let a committee know that the paper you list in the CV as under review, can be sent "on request". There is no real need to make it public for such limited distribution. You still own the copyright and a journal is very unlikely to object to such sharing. When asked for a copy, just indicate that it is "not for distribution."

Just don't make assumptions about what the journal permits.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Buffy... Just a doubt about "You can also let a committee know that the paper you list in the CV as under review, can be sent "on request"."..... If I send them the paper, and I do not get that position, who guarantees me that they don't try to reproduce the paper, or part of it, and then quickly publish it (and I lose then any evidence of priority), since the paper has not any licence or time-stamp connected to it, as when posted through arXiv or similar repositories?

Comment: That is unlikely. People are generally honest about such things, especially those trusted to hire others. Put a copyright notice in the paper. The journal has also seen your work, of course.

Comment: If you don't/can't trust the hiring committee don't apply there.